# Easy way to assess whether one data.table is a subset of another?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm hoping to avoid writing a function to detect whether all rows of one data.table exist in another data.table in R. For example:

```
library(data.table)
t1=data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c(1,2),d=c(5,6,7,8,9))
t2=data.table(x=c(2,3),x2=c(2,1),x3=c(6,7))
t3=data.table(y1=c(2,4), y2=c(2,2), y3=c(6,8))
```

I would want the function (again, preferably something data.table can already do easily, but if not that's okay, too) to return TRUE for both t2 and t3.

Comment: There is a warning message for t1. Are you aware?

Comment: Have you tried `t2==t3`. Are you happy with that output?

Comment: @MaxPD, yep I'm aware. Good eye, though. Re: t2==t3, not quite was I was looking for...

Comment: There's some combination of `apply` with an anonymous function that will do this. However (a) I can't find it right now, because it's Saturday night and I have better ways to spend Saturday night [no offense intended] and (b) an anonymous function is still a function and tying yourself in knots trying to avoid writing a named function is probably more of a PITA than it's worth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a join and check for equality of all the elements:

```
nms <- names(t2)
all(t1[t2, on=c(a=nms[1], b=nms[2], d=nms[3])] == t2, nomatch = 0L)
```

Or joining using keys:

```
setkey(t1)
# setkey(t2) not absolutely necessary

all(t1[t2, nomatch = 0L] == t2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

You could also use `intersect` if you have `dplyr` loaded (Thanks @Frank).

```
library(dplyr)
all(intersect(unname(t2), unname(t1)) == t2)
# alternatively: 
# all(intersect(t1, setNames(t2, names(t1))) == t2)
#[1] TRUEd
all(intersect(unname(t3), unname(t1)) == t3)
# alternatively: 
# all(intersect(t1, setNames(t3, names(t1))) == t3)
#[1] TRUE
```

The above will throw an error if t2 is not the same size as the intersection of t1 and t2.  The following will return `FALSE` instead of an error in that situation.

```
dim(intersect(t1, setNames(t2, names(t1))))[1] == dim(t2)[1]
#[1] TRUE
dim(intersect(t1, setNames(t3, names(t1))))[1] == dim(t3)[1]
#[1] TRUE
```

Note that these answers depend on order, and you may need to reorder to account for that if your situation requires it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! All great ideas!

Comment: The `intersect` thing only works because you have loaded dplyr. Also, I guess it is sensitive to the order that the rows show up in the intersection. With that loaded, another way to go would be `sapply(list(t2,t3), . %>% unname %>% setdiff(unname(t1)) %>% {nrow(.)==0})`.

Comment: @Jota, your solution using keys actually looks like it's a join. So, for instance, if we have `t4=data.table(x1=c(1,1), x2=c(1,1), x3=c(1,1))` and then ask `all(t1[t4] == t4)`, it also returns TRUE, which is _not_ a behavior we're hoping to see. Could I trouble you to edit the answer?

Comment: @Atticus29 I updated my answer.  Yes, using the key is still a join.  In the example in your comment, you can add `nomatch = 0L`.